# SharePoint Showing a mht file securly

Tags: html, iframe, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, mhtml

On my sharepoint I can display my excel file in mht file. but when I get to display the aspx page it keeps asking me if I want to display all content.

I know I just need to change the way the sharepoint goes to the source but if I do change it, the file just try's to download. I do not want that. I wanted to display a directory page that has a few mht files. and while I can display it, it keeps displaying a warning saying its only displaying secure content. How should I go about this, I know it needs to be https but how do I go about this ???

```
<p>
<strong>
<iframe align="middle" src="\\sharepoint.company.com\sites\Display\SitePages\HTML\Type\fileA.mht" width="100%" height="150%" scrolling="no"  ></iframe>
</strong>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I had to do was post it as a iframe with a separate page. that got rid of the security problem.

```
<strong>
<iframe align="middle" src="\\sharepoint.company.com\sites\Display\SitePages\HTML\Type\fileA.aspx" width="100%" height="400px" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```